# working on a GET variabile on dropzone

Tags: forms, get

Hi I'm passing a GET variable from a dropzone form as an input hidden field and the variable is printed correctly before entering in the  if (!empty($_FILES)) {   then in the if brankets the variable seems empty. 
Any idea about how i could resolve this problem ? I need to link the image to the id and store it in the db

```
$storeFolder = '../uploads';   //2
    $idimm= $_GET['idimm'];
$newnamef=$idimm."_";

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

     $newname=$newnamef.$_FILES['file']['name'];   
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             


    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath.$_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile )){  //6
    $file2=compress($_FILES['file']['name'],$targetPath,$newname);

     $conn->query("INSERT INTO foto (idimm,percorso,percorsotmp, dataupl) VALUES('$idimm','".$file2."','','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem, I need to add the get value not only with hidden input but also in the url in the dropzone script